# Removing sequence character from string JAVA

Tags: java, string, character, sequence, trim

The input will be like,

> ***hiii, i love java soooo much***

and the expected output will be like

> ***hi, i love java so much***

For my vague coding is as follows,

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(word.split(""));
String previousCharacter;
boolean inneFlag = false;
boolean flag = false;
int iterator = 0;
int characterIterator = 0;
String finalizedWord = "";
previousCharacter = wordList.get(0);
for(String character : wordList){
    if((wordList.size()-1)==characterIterator){
          inneFlag = true;
     }
     if(flag){
         if(character.equalsIgnoreCase(previousCharacter)){
              iterator++;
              if(inneFlag){
                   if(iterator>2){
                        finalizedWord = finalizedWord.substring(0,(finalizedWord.length()-iterator));
                    }
               }
         }else{
              previousCharacter = character;
              if(iterator>=2){
                  finalizedWord = finalizedWord.substring(0,(finalizedWord.length()-iterator));
              }
              iterator = 0;
           }
       }else{
            flag = true;
       }
    characterIterator++;
    finalizedWord += character;
}
```

Can anyone give better solution??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple regex will do this job.

```
string.replaceAll("([A-Za-z])\\1+", "$1");
```

or

```
string.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5bG5/5)

Comment: thank u! i better should learn how to use regex pattern technique!! ;)